Copy or create an image into every folder created by an Apple Script
I've written an AppleScript that creates a folder structure of my photography workflow. This script works great. However, since Adobe Lightroom won't recognize an empty folder, I'm trying to figure out how to copy (or create) a placeholder image into each folder that script creates, but I can't get figure out how to do it. Here is the folder script:
set loc to (choose folder with prompt "Choose the folder location:")
set ClientCode to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter the client code:" default answer "XXX")
set ShootName to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter the shoot name:" default answer "Product Shoot")
set OutputName to "2 - Output"
set ProdName to "1 -  Production"
set FinalImageName to ShootName & " Final Images"
set SelectImageName to ShootName & " Image Selects"


tell application "Finder"
    activate
    make new folder at loc with properties {name:ShootName}
    open folder ShootName of folder loc
    set current view of window 1 to list view
    
    set RAWFname to "1 - " & ClientCode & " RAW Files" as string
    set SelectsFname to "2 - " & ClientCode & " Selects" as string
    set RetouchingFname to "3 - " & ClientCode & " For Retouching" as string
    set MastersFname to "4 - " & ClientCode & " Master Final Files" as string
    set WebsiteFname to "5 - " & ClientCode & " For Website" as string
    
    
    make new folder at folder ShootName of folder loc with properties {name:OutputName}
    make new folder at folder OutputName of folder ShootName of folder loc with properties {name:SelectImageName}
    make new folder at folder OutputName of folder ShootName of folder loc with properties {name:FinalImageName}
    make new folder at folder FinalImageName of folder OutputName of folder ShootName of folder loc with properties {name:"2500px JPGs"}
    make new folder at folder FinalImageName of folder OutputName of folder ShootName of folder loc with properties {name:"Full Res JPGs"}
    
    make new folder at folder ShootName of folder loc with properties {name:ProdName}
    make new folder at folder ProdName of folder ShootName of folder loc with properties {name:RAWFname}
    make new folder at folder ProdName of folder ShootName of folder loc with properties {name:SelectsFname}
    make new folder at folder ProdName of folder ShootName of folder loc with properties {name:RetouchingFname}
    make new folder at folder ProdName of folder ShootName of folder loc with properties {name:MastersFname}
    make new folder at folder ProdName of folder ShootName of folder loc with properties {name:WebsiteFname}
    
    
end tell


Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!
Thanks, —b
I tried to have ChatGPT write a simple script that would copy an existing image but I ran into permission issues and how to get the script to see the folders the script had already created.
set destinationPath to POSIX path of RAWFname

set imagePath to POSIX path of "/Users/myusername/camera.jpg" 

do shell script "cp " & quoted form of POSIX path of imagePath & " " & quoted form of POSIX path of destinationPath


Does the placeholder need to be an image, or can it be an empty text file?

Yes, it must be an image file, preferable a JPG.

This should do what you need. Given that you're using regular applescript to create the folder tree, you may as well stick with it for the camera file duplication.
For the make command, you can assign the result to a variable. For example, the first use of the command —that makes the 'Product Shoot' folder— would return the following in addition to actually creating the folder:

folder "Product Shoot" of folder "testo" of folder "Desktop" of folder "username" of folder "Users" of startup disk

By assigning it to the variable f0, we can use it later to build the list of created folders, as well as to open the 'Product Shoot' folder.
as string is redundant, since the first item in each command is already a text string.
set loc to (choose folder with prompt "Choose the folder location:")
set ClientCode to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter the client code:" default answer "XXX")
set ShootName to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter the shoot name:" default answer "Product Shoot")
set OutputName to "2 - Output"
set ProdName to "1 -  Production"
set FinalImageName to ShootName & " Final Images"
set SelectImageName to ShootName & " Image Selects"

set imagePath to ((path to home folder) & "camera.png" as text) -- path to 'camera' file

tell application "Finder"
    activate
    set f0 to make new folder at loc with properties {name:ShootName}
    open f0
    set current view of window 1 to list view
    
    set RAWFname to "1 - " & ClientCode & " RAW Files"
    set SelectsFname to "2 - " & ClientCode & " Selects" 
    set RetouchingFname to "3 - " & ClientCode & " For Retouching" 
    set MastersFname to "4 - " & ClientCode & " Master Final Files" 
    set WebsiteFname to "5 - " & ClientCode & " For Website" 
    
    set f2 to make new folder at folder ShootName of folder loc with properties {name:OutputName}
    set f21 to make new folder at folder OutputName of folder ShootName of folder loc with properties {name:SelectImageName}
    set f22 to make new folder at folder OutputName of folder ShootName of folder loc with properties {name:FinalImageName}
    set f22a to make new folder at folder FinalImageName of folder OutputName of folder ShootName of folder loc with properties {name:"2500px JPGs"}
    set f22b to make new folder at folder FinalImageName of folder OutputName of folder ShootName of folder loc with properties {name:"Full Res JPGs"}
    
    set f1 to make new folder at folder ShootName of folder loc with properties {name:ProdName}
    set f1a to make new folder at folder ProdName of folder ShootName of folder loc with properties {name:RAWFname}
    set f1b to make new folder at folder ProdName of folder ShootName of folder loc with properties {name:SelectsFname}
    set f1c to make new folder at folder ProdName of folder ShootName of folder loc with properties {name:RetouchingFname}
    set f1d to make new folder at folder ProdName of folder ShootName of folder loc with properties {name:MastersFname}
    set f1e to make new folder at folder ProdName of folder ShootName of folder loc with properties {name:WebsiteFname}
    
    set fList to {}
    -- broken into three segments to simplify
    set fList to {f0} & {f2, f21, f22, f22a, f22b} -- f0 is the 'product shoot' folder, f1 branch is production, f2 branch is output;
    set fList to fList & {f1, f1a, f1b, f1c, f1d, f1e}
    -- could also do this: 
    -- set fList to {f0 ,f2, f21, f22, f22a, f22b,f1, f1a, f1b, f1c, f1d, f1e}
    
    repeat with f in fList -- cycle through each created folder
        set ft to f as text -- convert finder reference (eg 'file x of folder y) to file reference (eg MacHD:Users:username:2 Output)
        duplicate file imagePath to folder ft -- duplicate 'camera' file to each folder in list
    end repeat
    
end tell

Notes on paths
The path —when using this 'colon' or 'HFS' style— must begin with the name of the drive. The easiest way to do this for an item that is in the home folder, is to use the path to command. path to home folder will generate 'Macintosh HD:Users:b:', assuming that the username is 'b'. This command below will generate the following path: "Macintar:Users:b:camera.jpg"
Put this command in a new script by itself and run it.

set imagePath to (path to home folder as text) & "camera.jpg"
--> "Macintar:Users:b:camera.jpg"

Note that once you get the exact result you want, you could then
set the variable to that path directly.

set imagePath to "Macintar:Users:b:camera.jpg"
--> "Macintar:Users:b:camera.jpg"

You can also use (path to desktop) to generate the path to the 'Product Shoot' folder. Note that unlike 'home folder', the 'desktop' doesn't include the word 'folder'.

set shootName to (path to desktop as text) & "Folder Setup Scripts:Product Shoot:"
--> "Macintar:Users:b:Desktop:Folder Setup Scripts:Product Shoot:"


Thank you very much! I tried it but I am getting an error:
error "Finder got an error: Can’t set folder "Macintosh HD:Users:b:Desktop:Folder Setup Scripts:Product Shoot:" to file ":Users:bcamera.jpg"." number -10006 from folder "Macintosh HD:Users:b:Desktop:Folder Setup Scripts:Product Shoot:"
I updated script with the path to the "camera.jpg" image as: **set imagePath to ":Users:b" & "camera.jpg" as text **. I think the issue is with the path and I'll keep playing with it.
Thanks again for your quick response and help!

It looks like you're mixing and matching some things to try and get the paths that you want. What is the line that is generating that error?

I'm not trying to mix or match. I just took your script and updated the path to the camera jpg. Here is what the error says:
error "Finder got an error: Can’t set folder "Macintosh HD:Users:b:Desktop:Folder Setup Scripts:Product Shoot 3:" to file "Machintosh HD:Users:b:camera.jpg"." number -10006 from folder "Macintosh HD:Users:b:Desktop:Folder Setup Scripts:Product Shoot 3:"

My mistake. Which command line in the script produced the error? The 'duplicate' line? Regarding the path to the camera… the path has an extraneous 'h' in 'Machintosh'.

Actually, it was mine. The extra "h" was the problem! Thanks again for your help!

I've collected a handful of folder structure handlers over the years, the following includes one that uses recursion to step through a (nested) list that declares the structure.  While it is stepping through each item in the list, it is fairly easy to add stuff like putting a dummy file in the created folders.  In this example I am just duplicating an image from the Pictures folder, which can be small, hidden, or whatever, as desired.
set loc to (choose folder with prompt "Choose the folder location:")
set ClientCode to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter the client code:" default answer "XXX")
set ShootName to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter the shoot name:" default answer "Product Shoot")

set ProdName to "1 -  Production"
set OutputName to "2 - Output"
set FinalImageName to ShootName & " Final Images"
set SelectImageName to ShootName & " Image Selects"
set RAWFname to "1 - " & ClientCode & " RAW Files"
set SelectsFname to "2 - " & ClientCode & " Selects"
set RetouchingFname to "3 - " & ClientCode & " For Retouching"
set MastersFname to "4 - " & ClientCode & " Master Final Files"
set WebsiteFname to "5 - " & ClientCode & " For Website"

set structure to {ShootName, {OutputName, {SelectImageName, FinalImageName, {"2500px JPGs", "Full Res JPGs"}}, ProdName, {RAWFname, SelectsFname, RetouchingFname, MastersFname, WebsiteFname}}}

if (makeFolderStructure out of structure at loc) then
   tell application "Finder"
      activate
      open folder ShootName of folder loc
      set current view of window 1 to list view
   end tell
else
   display alert "Script Error" message "There was an error creating the folder structure."
end if


# Make a folder structure from a list of folder names.
# Nested list items create folders in the previous item, for example:
#  {"A", {"B",{"D", "E"}, "C"}, "F"} results in "A" and "F" in the main folder, "B" and "C" in "A", and "D" and "E" in "B"
to makeFolderStructure out of (folderList as list) at someFolder
   set {currentParent, success} to {someFolder, true}
   repeat with anItem in folderList
      if class of anItem is list then -- add sub structure(s) to the current parent
         set success to (makeFolderStructure out of anItem at currentParent)
      else -- add a folder to the current parent
         tell application "Finder" to try
            set currentParent to (make new folder at someFolder with properties {name:anItem}) as alias
            my doExtraStuff(currentParent)
         on error errmess number errnum
            if errnum is -48 then -- already exists
               set currentParent to folder anItem of someFolder -- continue
            else
               set success to false
            end if
         end try
      end if
   end repeat
   return success
end makeFolderStructure

# Copy a dummy item to each folder so that it is not empty.
to doExtraStuff(parentFolder)
   set dummyFile to ((path to pictures folder) as text) & "_dummy.jpg" -- or whatever
   tell application "Finder" to duplicate dummyFile to parentFolder
end doExtraStuff

